# The meaning of "as"

Tags: adverbial-phrases, as

What is the meaning of "as" in the following sentences?

1. Nature’s editors rejected the paper (and will not, **as is normal procedure in the case of rejection**, confirm that they actually received it).
2. **As is so often pointed out**, knowledge is a two-edged weapon which can be used equally for good or evil.
3. **As is usual in armed conflict**, it is the civilian population that suffers the most.
4. **As with his earlier movies**, the special effects in his latest film are brilliant.
5. Sound and pictures can be stored digitally, **as on a CD.**

Comment: This is the comparative use of "as", where it has the clauses or PPs as complement -- the PPs function as comparative adjuncts. The expressions that follow the emboldened ones are called the 'secondary terms'. They complete the comparative meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This form of "as is" / "as with"  is primarily used when the other clause is the main idea that the speaker is trying to communicate, while the "as" phrase is used as a modifier that compares this idea to some more general case, often suggesting that it is common or generally true.

Usually, you can form an equivalent sentence by replacing "as is" with a phrase starting with "like" or "which". For example, I have written each of your example sentences in an alternative form without "as is" / "as with" / etc, replacing them with a clause beginning with "like" or "which":

> 1) *Nature’s editors rejected the paper and will not confirm that they
>   actually received it, **which** is normal procedure in the case of
>   rejection.*
>
> 2) *Knowledge is a two-edged weapon which can be used equally for good
>   or evil, **which** is something that people often point out.*
>
> 3) *It is the civilian population that suffers first, **which** is true of armed
>   conflict in general.*
>
> 4) *The special effects in his latest film are brilliant, **like** those in
>   his earlier movies*.
>
> 5) *Sound and pictures can be stored digitally, **like** they are on a CD.*